# Get authentification user and password from QGIS' authentification store

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, authentication

I stored a basic authentication configuration in QGIS' authentication manager. I only set its name, id, username and password.

How can I read the username and password from it using the PyQGIS API?

```
authManager = QgsApplication.authManager()
configs = authManager.availableAuthMethodConfigs()
test_config = configs["configa"]
```

test_config is a [`QgsAuthMethodConfig`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsAuthMethodConfig.html) object.

Here is what I can query from it:

```
test_config.id()  # "configa"
test_config.name()  # "myname"
test_config.method()  # "Basic"
test_config.version()  # 2
test_config.uri()  # ""
test_config.configMap()  # {}
```

How do I get the username and password from it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825350/4828720 I found a solution. Not sure if this is actually abuse of the API or the intended way though:

```py
authManager = QgsApplication.authManager()
success, decrypted_config = authManager.loadAuthenticationConfig(
    "configa",  # the id of the existing configuration to load (7 chars)
    QgsAuthMethodConfig(),  # a fresh new config object
    full=True,  # whether to decrypt the credentials
)
if success:
  print(decrypted_config.configMap())
```

gives

```
{'password': 'mypassword', 'realm': '', 'username': 'myuser'}
```

If QGIS has a master password set, this will halt and prompt the user with a dialog before decrypting. If the user is unsuccessful in entering the valid master password, the resulting new config will not include the decrypted credentials and the `success` flag will be `False`.